# Picoblaze assembly How to add 16bits to itself

Tags: assembly, picoblaze

I have 8bits register s3 is the LSB 0x00 of the display
I also have 8bits register s4 is the MSB 0x00 of the display
The display shows as s4/s3 0000 which is 16 bits values

When the display has a value 0x0103, I want to add it to itselt assembly picoblaze.
I cannot find a way to do it.
As I know I can do

```
ADD s3, s3
ADDCY s4, 00
```

which will add 8bits s3 to itself and shift the Carry to s4, but it is not what I want.
Is there  a way that I can add s4/s3 to itself.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `ADD s3, s3; ADDCY s4, s4`?

Comment: @fuz, I tried like your suggestion, but s4 does not give me the correct answer. s3 does give me the correct answer.

Comment: It should work.  Have you given these two instructions after each other in the order I gave them?

Comment: Which result do you get? 0x0103 * 2 = 0x0206

Comment: When I do the x30*x04, I got x00c0 which is correct. But when I do xc0*x04 i got x0700 instead of x0300. There is something wrong with the ADDCY s4,s4

Comment: I have the multiply like this:
multop: ADD s3, sD 
  ADDCY s4, s4
  SUB sC, 01
  JUMP NZ, multop

Comment: What are your intermediate results? E.g. from xc0*x01, xc0*x02, xc0*x03?